# How to refresh child object in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have 2 table property and property_type

```
property's columns: id, name, property_type_id, style, ...., status, create_at, update_at

property_type's columns: id, name, status, create_at, update_at
```

**property_type_id** column is mapping with **property_type** table

Here my code

```
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $propertyData = $entityManager->getRepository('PropertyBundle:Property')->find(4);
    $propertyType = $propertyData->getPropertyTypeId();

    if($propertyData->getStatus() == 1) {
        $propertyData->setName('test1');
        $propertyType->setName('test1');
    } else if($propertyData->getStatus() == 2) {
        $propertyData->setName('test2');
        $propertyType->setName('test2');
    }

   if($propertyData->getStyle() == 1) {
       // only refresh $propertyType object
        $entityManager->refresh($propertyType) 
    }
```

I am trying to refresh only **$propertyType** but according above code **$propertyType** and **$propertyData** both objects are getting refreshed.

Comment: What kind of association mapping do you have set on `propertyType`? Have you mapped the inverse relationship for `propertyData::propertyType`?

Comment: doctrine's default change tracking is this: whenever you change something on a managed object and call `flush`, that change is written to db. `refresh` overrides the object's data from the database (refreshes a dirty, i.e. modified, object). I have this feeling that you do either have a misconception about that or you have a code smell (or you happen to omit the fact, you changed the tracking policy)

Comment: Many to one(m:1) relation between property and propertyType with inverse mapping.

Comment: `UnitOfWork::refresh()` will follow mapped associations. Since you have the inverse mapping declared, and both objects are in memory, `refresh()` will act on both.